# Setting a part of the cell contents to bold using apache poi?

Tags: java, html, apache-poi

How can i put this string in to a cell using java apache poi?
The string is "Hello **world** Hello"
As u can see i need to make a part of the text bold? 
I'm able to set the entire contents of the cell to bold but not specific parts. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DrawingShapes

Find this in the explanation:

> It's possible to use different fonts to style parts of the text in the textbox. Here's how:

```
HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
font.setItalic(true);
font.setUnderline(HSSFFont.U_DOUBLE);
HSSFRichTextString string = new HSSFRichTextString("Woo!!!");
string.applyFont(2,5,font);
textbox.setString(string );
```

This might be useful: http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Multiple-text-styles-in-Excel-cell-td4922683.html

Answer (score 8):

This will print "Hello **world** Hello" in a cell

```
XSSFRichTextString rts= new XSSFRichTextString("Hello ");

XSSFFont fontBold= wb.createFont();
fontBold.setBold(true); //set bold
fontBold.setFontHeight(12); //add font size

rts.append("world ",fontBold);
rts.append("Hello");

sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).setCellValue(rts);
```

Comment: In my case it asks me to cast Font to XSSFFont

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.setValue(value);
RichTextString rts = cell.getRichStringCellValue();
rts.applyFont(value.indexOf(subValue), value.length(), boldFonts);
cell.setCellValue(rts);
```

Where value=something+subValue. Here subValue contents will be with bold fonts.
for example if we have someting="Hello" and subValue="world" we will print:

Hello **world**

in the cell.