# Apache POI: Show HTML text in Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

Need a help. Honestly I don't have a clue now how to start on this.

```
<p>This is a test. Will this text be <b>bold</b> or <i>italic</i></p>
```

So in my excel, it should be

This is a test. Will this text be **bold** or *italic*

Again, I do have example which write this as plain text. Could anyone please help me in making this text as Rich Text in excel. Note: this is just an example. In realtime, it could be any html with styles.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697330/setting-a-part-of-the-cell-contents-to-bold-using-apache-poi

Comment: You probably should read http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Cells+with+multiple+styles+%28Rich+Text+Strings%29

Comment: "In realtime, it could be any html with styles.": Then you will need a HTML parser - a tag soup parser like internet browsers have - before you can creating [Rich Text Strings](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Cells+with+multiple+styles+%28Rich+Text+Strings%29). Thats not trivial and so cannot be totally answered in a question here. Choose a HTML parser for Java and try something. Then come back with a concrete question if you are stuck.