# Add subscript in cell text using Apache POI Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to display value in cell as "Total CO<sub>2</sub> emission in 2016 is 2 468 Kgs"

I am using setCellValue() function as:

> setCellValue("Total CO2 emission in 2016 is " + emission)

I found that there is field SS_SUB [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FontFormatting.SS_SUB) in the documentation, how can I use it?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697330/setting-a-part-of-the-cell-contents-to-bold-using-apache-poi) post shows how to set partial text bold in a text. But there is nothing to format text with subscript.

Comment: "But there is nothing to format text with subscript." What about just applying a `Font` having [setTypeOffset](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html#setTypeOffset(short))? Exactly like the example applies a `Font` which is being italic and underlined.

Comment: Thanks, that works :)